# How to rollback changes to VSAM file on CICS?

Tags: cics

I'm using EXEC CICS SYNCPOINT and EXEC CICS SYNCPOINT ROLLBACK to commit/backout updates to VSAM and DB2 tables when abend happens. However, only updates to DB2 tables are backed out not on VSAM. Am I missing something? CICS parameter RLS is set to RLS=NO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will depend on the type of files that you are using.  If you are using RLS files then you have to define the files correctly using idcams using the LOG parameter see:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=cics-recoverable-nonrecoverable-data-sets

If you are using non-RLS files then you need to set the attributes correctly on your FILE definition.

See the following page within the CICS documentation that describes about file recovery:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=resources-recovery-files

Comment: If my CICS parameter is set to RLS=NO, will any of the two methods above work?

Comment: If you have RLS=NO specified then you will need to ensure you have the file attributes correctly set eg RECOVERY / FWDRECOVLOG dependent on what you required for your application. See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=resources-vsam-files-accessed-in-non-rls-mode for more details specific Non RLS recovery.  Also look at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=resources-file-attributes for more in-depth information about the file attributes.

Comment: This is good. Would you consider editing the information in your comment into your answer?